# Return True When Time fall between a Time Range?

Tags: c#

I am making a function to check time fall between a time range in 24hr format, However there is some thing wrong with my code , can any one point out how to fix ?

My code:

```
bool isDoTime(int starthour, int startminute, int endhour, int endminute)
    {
        TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(starthour, startminute, 0); 
        TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(endhour, endminute, 0);
        TimeSpan add24h = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;


        if (starthour > endhour || (endhour == starthour && endminute <= startminute))
        {
            end += add24h;
        }
        if ((now > start) && (now < end))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Problem: i want to return true when current time between 20:30  - 3:30 , however when i run my code as below. the condition is return true only from 8:30 to 00:00 , not true from 00:00 - 3:30

```
if (isDoTime(20,30,3,30) //return true from 20:30  - 3:30 
{
   //dosomething
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you convert that endtime 3:30 into 27:30, but you don't convert a current time of 2:30 into 26:30.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split up in one check if it spans across midninght, and one for same day.

```
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(starthour, startminute, 0); 
TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(endhour, endminute, 0);
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

//The readable version:
if(start>end){
  //Must check if after start (before midnight) or before end (after midnight)
  if((now > start) || (now < end)){
    return true;
  {
}
else
{
  //Simple check - span is within same day
  if ((now > start) && (now < end))
  {
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

The short/cryptic version:

```
return start > end ? (now > start) || (now < end) : (now > start) && (now < end);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `DateTime` structures rather than integers. You can also generalise it to arbitary DateTimes. If `secondTime` is less than `firstTime`, it adds 1 day to `secondTime`.

```
public bool IsBetween(this DateTime thisTime, DateTime firstTime, DateTime secondTime) {
    if (secondTime < firstTime)
        secondTime = secondTime.AddDays(1);
    return firstTime < thisTime && thisTime < secondTime);
}

// to use...
bool isDoTime = DateTime.Now.IsBetween(firstTime, secondTime);
```

Comment: What about the case where the start time is greater than the end time?

Comment: Thanks, but i am writing this to work on an api which require to input hour/minute as integers, and it required to check the condition daily basic..can you point out the solution ?

Comment: @Bakerh: you can get the hour & minute as properties of the `DateTime` object - `DateTime.Hour`, `DateTime.Minute`

Comment: **Bakerh** said that it has to work on an API using integers - it has nothing to do with the possibility to get the values from a `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off using `DateTime` however, you will still need to check that if the start time is greater than the end time and add 24 hours in that case.

Your method would start:

```
bool isDoTime(int starthour, int startminute, int endhour, int endminute)
{
    DateTime start = new DateTime(0, 0, 0, starthour, startminute, 0); 
    DateTime end = new DateTime(0, 0, 0, endhour, endminute, 0);
    if (start > end)
    {
        end.AddDays(1);
    }
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    return start < now && now < end;
}
```

Though you might want `<=` tests depending on your logic

(Unless it's your logic of where you're adding 24 hours of course - does that code execute?)

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier to make to use DateTime's as parameters here, and avoid the whole problem of manually checking:

```
bool isDoTime(DateTime starttime, DateTime endtime)
{
  if (DateTime.Now > starttime && DateTime.Now < endtime)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The OP still needs to add 24 hours to the end time if the start time is greater than the end time.

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        private DateTime _now;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _now = DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(1).AddHours(2); //02.01.0001 02:00:00
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestCase()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(IsDoTime(20, 30, 3, 30));
        }

        bool IsDoTime(int starthour, int startminute, int endhour, int endminute)
        {
            var start1 = DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(starthour).AddMinutes(startminute); //01.01.0001 20:30:00

            var end1 = endhour < starthour
                           ? DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(1).AddHours(endhour).AddMinutes(endminute) //02.01.0001 03:30:00
                           : DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(endhour).AddMinutes(endminute);

            return ((_now > start1) && (_now < end1));
        }
    }
```